# Tablet Screen Issue

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, apk, smali

I'm trying to rewrite an app to fit my screen.. everything works full screen now but the control surface screen :(

so here's picture of my screen

http://www.mediafire.com/imageview.php?quickkey=j6r0okbmbfd3a24&thumb=4

the layout that's in red should be full screen, and it is but the frame is locking it up..
so I cant see the full layout

http://www.mediafire.com/?p300cpn0t7634v5

apk file.. HELP!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The solution for me was to change the minimum sdk version in the AndroidManifest.xml to higher. I had mine set to 2. I personally changed mine to 7 and the problem went away but I'm not sure how low you can go here.

In the AndroidManifest.xml add/change

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
```

Comment: well I changed that.. main menu and options changed to proper resolution.. but the main controll window/suface still small.. but with new Honeycomb 3.2 zoom fixes it.. but not i have to change the layouts :( I also figured out that it's in smalli files.. and it's lots of messing with hex.. so I just might switch the layouts